# AS3: An interface implements another interface

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, actionscript, flash-builder

I am so surprised that this code compiles, but what does it mean ?

```
public interface IBar {}
public interface IFoo implements IBar {}
```

Comment: Perhaps this depends on the compiler, but since an interface cannot literally implement anything, a "smart" compiler can interpret "implements" as "extends" and act accordingly. Do you mind giving the info on what is the compiler you use that compiles this?

Comment: FlashBuilder 4.6 on Mac OS X.

Comment: I've re-tagged your question as for FlashBuilder. Be sure that next time you'll tag your question accurately.

Comment: It also compiles on FlashDevelop 4.2.1 on Windows. Consider to remove the tag ?

Answer (score 4):

It can't be compiled because interface can't `implement` the other interface but can `extends` it:

```
public interface IFoo extends IBar {}
```

Your code must leads to error:

```
1084: Syntax error: expecting leftbrace before implements.
```

Comment: It DOES compiles in my IDE: FlashBuilder 4.6 on Mac OS X.

Comment: There should be explanation why you think it compiles, may be this code exists in your project but actually doesn't compiled because of it isn't used. [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/77217007/stackoverflow/15133273-as3-an-interface-implements-another-interface/astest.as) is the example check it your SDK. Screenshot for SDK 4.6 http://pix.am/RK0b.png of this example. In any case there is the only sense in such language structure - extending interfaces.

Comment: It also compiles on FlashDevelop 4.2.1 on Windows. SDK: Flex 4.6.0. The code I shown is actually some code we're using in the production.